# Interface for object typescript/ionic 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a json object returned from an api and want to create an interface with fields that the object contains. I am using ionic 3 framework. I want help in how to create this interface.( i am confused: should i create another interface for data? and how to include it in the main interface if yes?) the object structure is as follows:

```
{

"status": "success",

"data": [

      {

          "id": 113,

          "subject": "hello there",

          "body": "i am hisham",

          "sender": {

              "id": 51,

              "country": {

                  "id": 9,

                  "name_en": "Syria",

              }

          }

      },

      {

          "id": 114,

          "subject": "hello there",

          "body": "i am lkfdj",

          "sender": {

              "id": 54,

              "country": {

                  "id": 9,

                  "name_en": "Syria",
              }

          }

      }

  ]

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're defining interfaces, you should define one for each object in your response. You don't have to, but to get proper type completion, you should.

```
interface Response {
  status: string;
  data: Data[];
}

interface Data {
  id: number;
  subject: string;
  body: string;
  sender: Sender;
}

interface Sender {
  id: number;
  country: Country;
}

interface Country {
  id: number;
  name_en: string;
}
```